# Reproduce the annulus fractal

Tags: graphics, iteration, fractals

[image]
I've made some attempts, but I don't know how to set the color and thickness of the circle.

```
Graphics[{
NestList[#/.Circle[{x_,y_},R_]->With[{r=1/2R},
Append[Table[Circle[{x,y}+(R+r)/2 {Cos@#,Sin@#},(R-r)/2]&[2k Pi/4],{k,0,3}],
Circle[{x,y},r]]]&,Circle[{0,0},1],4]
}]
```

Comment: You can use `Torus` in `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, a variation on @azerbajdzan's approach to *subdivide* an annulus:

```
ClearAll[step]
step = ReplaceAll[Annulus[c_, r_] :> With[{rr = r + Subtract @@ r}, Flatten @
   {an[c, r], Annulus[c, rr/2], 
    Annulus[c + r[[1]] #, rr/4] & /@
      {{0, 3/4}, {0, -3/4}, {3/4, 0}, {-3/4, 0}}}]];
```

Next, a function to re-render an annulus using `ParametricPlot`:

```
ClearAll[annulusToPP]
annulusToPP[Annulus[c_, r_]] := First @ 
 ParametricPlot[{s  Cos[θ], s  Sin[θ]} + c, 
   {θ, 0, 2 π}, {s, r[[1]], r[[2]]}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {r}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[
       Thread[{{r[[1]], Mean@r, r[[2]]}, {#, Lighter[#, .95], #} &@
          Hue[#3/2/Pi]}], #4] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]


Graphics[
 Nest[step, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 1.15}], 3] /. an -> Annulus /. 
  a_Annulus :> annulusToPP[a], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

There is some bug in `ConicGradientFilling` if more than `2` colors are used. (see line at right of each annulus)

Bellow are images with number of colors in gradient `nc=2` and `nc=6`.

```
rule = Annulus[{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}] -> 
   Sequence @@ {an[{x, y}, {a, b}], 
     Annulus[{x, y}, ({a, b} - (b - a))/2], 
     Annulus[{x - 3/4*a, y}, ({a, b} - (b - a))/4], 
     Annulus[{x + 3/4*a, y}, ({a, b} - (b - a))/4], 
     Annulus[{x, y - 3/4*a}, ({a, b} - (b - a))/4], 
     Annulus[{x, y + 3/4*a}, ({a, b} - (b - a))/4]};
nc = 6;

Nest[# /. rule &, {Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}]}, 5] /. an -> Annulus /. 
  x_Annulus :> {ConicGradientFilling[
     RandomChoice[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], nc]], x} // Graphics
```

---

[image]

[image]

With `Graphics[#, Background -> Black] &` colors are maybe more perceptible.

[image]

Comment: +1 Very nice, Indeed!

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by @kglr, this is a faster version

```
Clear["`*"];
r1=0.9; s=1/2; n=4;
step=GeometricTransformation[#,Append[Table[AffineTransform[{(1-s)/2 {{r1,0},{0,r1}},
  r1 (1+s)/2 {Cos@#,Sin@#}&[2k Pi/n ]}],{k,0,n-1}],ScalingTransform[s r1{1,1}]]]&;

img=Visualization`Core`ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t],r Sin[t]},{t,0,2Pi},{r,r1,1},
  PlotPoints->90,Mesh->None,BoundaryStyle->None,Axes->False,Frame->False,
  PlotRangePadding->None,ImageSize->400{1,1},
  ColorFunction->(Blend[Thread[{{0,0.5,1},{#,Lighter[#,.8],#}&@Hue[#3]}],#4]&)
]//Rasterize;

level=5;
Graphics[{
  MapIndexed[{SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading",
  Texture@Darker[img,Rescale[Tr@#2,{1,level},{0,0.6}]]],#}&,
  NestList[step,Annulus[{0,0},{r1,1}],level-1]]
},ImageSize->Large,Background->Black,
  BaseStyle->{FilledCurveBoxOptions->{Method->{"SplinePoints"->60}}}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## In 3D

```
ClearAll[r];
r [{x_,y_,z_,r1_,r2_}]:={
   {x , y,z,r1/2,r2},
   {x - 3/4*r1, y,z,r1/4,r2},
   {x+ 3/4*r1, y,z,r1/4,r2},
   {x,y- 3/4*r1,z,r1/4,r2},
   {x,y+ 3/4*r1,z,r1/4,r2}
}

ClearAll[t];
t[{x_,y_,z_,r1_,r2_}]:=Torus[{x,y,z},{r1-r2,r1+r2}]

Graphics3D@Flatten@Map[
   t
   , NestList[Map[r,#, {-2}]&,{0,0,0,1,0.01},4]
   , {-2}
]
```

[image]